# How to replace text file content with 'sed' or 'awk' based on input originated from multiple-row printout of a different command?

Tags: string, bash, replace, awk, sed

Template file content (template.txt):

```
[Load]
 <CPU-ALL>
 <CPU-0>
 <CPU-1>
 <CPU-2>
 <CPU-3>
```

`mpstat -P ALL | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12 }'` command will give you the results for each in consecutive rows:

```
14
13
13
13
17
```

My aim is to replace all the `CPU-x` labels with the respective data using a new file as a destination (not to overwrite the template):

Result file (result.txt):

```
[Load]
 <14>
 <13>
 <13>
 <13>
 <17>
```

I just don't know how to do it in one command without executing mpstat four times for each data replacement - which is not a solution considering the delay that it would cause.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Does your template contains anything else?

Comment: Hi Ashkan,
Yes, it has. This is why I suppose something e.g. sed -i 's/original/new' result.txt should be used (maybe with copying template.txt to result.txt for first).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[i++]=$1;next}{if($1~/CPU-ALL|CPU-[0-9]+/) sub(/<CPU-ALL>|<CPU-[0-9]+>/,"<"a[j++]">")}1' <(mpstat -P ALL | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12 }') template.txt > result.txt
```

My template:

```
[load]
 <CPU-ALL>
 <CPU-0>
 <CPU-1>
```

Output:

```
[load]
 <52.3>
 <53.69>
 <50.92>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it gives me the following error message:

`Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: @Akos, this uses _Process Substitution_ which is not available in posix mode, so don't run it via sh if you are doing this now instead use bash. Also you can enable posix mode via set +o posix if it is not enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to this. If I execute it via bash ./script.sh, then it tells me that template doesn't exist: `awk: cannot open template (No such file or directory)`. Shouldn't the input file be template.txt (anyway, I tried that already, same error). I also don't see result.txt mentioned in the command you wrote. Have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: @Akos, Yes it must be template.txt or whatever your template file name is. To get results in a file name result.text you should redirect the output to it. Anyways, I edited it.